# Rails ERB -- get the generated HTML content to a variable I can access in a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, render, erb

I am doing an online contract agreement which is generated dynamically based on the current state of our contract language (stored in an ERB partial).

When the user clicks "I Agree" we save the variable data, but I also want to store the contents of the rendered partial (html fragment) in the database.

I tried using `ActionView::Helpers::CaptureHelper.capture` -- wrapping the whole partial in a block and rendering at the end, like

```
<% @saved_output = capture do %>
...
The rest of the erb with instance variable <%= @my_class.name %> and so on
...
<% end %>
<%= @saved_output %>
<% logger.debug "Rendered output is: #{@saved_output}" %>
```

And this produced the same result and also sent the correct text to the log.  But it appears to go out of scope -- even if I declare `@saved_output = nil` prior to render it's `nil` when I end the block.

I tried using `content_for` as well ... which makes some sense to me, but ... huh, just not getting it.  Any helpful pointers appreciated.

Comment: Why not save a revision of the contract every time the contract changes, and then simply reference which version of the contract the user agreed to?

Comment: Saving the versioned markup in the database is perhaps a more elegant solution, but very inconvenient in practice, since a minor contractual change requires a database update instead of a change via text editor ... or a view allowing me to edit a new version, etc.  We're in a very volatile stage of our company now -- both the variables and the boilerplate are changing (so *both* are versioned, in effect).  So while it's terribly inefficient to store the text repeatedly, until we have hundreds of contracts, my desired solution is simple and fast, and easily optimized later once we stabilize.

Comment: Surely you're using version control? Just reference the git SHA/SVN revision/whatever of the revision the ERB file is on when the user agrees to the contract.

Comment: Yes, we're using version control.  I could explain my entire business reasoning for my approach to the problem, but I was kinda hoping to figure out how to get the contents of some rendered `erb` into a variable.  Pretend for a moment that I have a good reason to do it the way I describe, k?

Comment: Fair enough :) Have you tried `render_to_string` in your controller when you're creating the record? That may allow you to just go ahead and "snapshot" the page.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for -- thanks for sticking with me :-)  I *knew* it was there somewhere but couldn't find it.  Add your comment as an answer and I'll mark it correct and give you major props.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `render_to_string` in your controller when you're creating the record? That may allow you to just go ahead and "snapshot" the page.